# Block traffic to Azure web Api which is associated to an ASE

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have created an App Service Environment and have multiple web app and web API associated with it. I want to achieve an arrangement where only my App service has access to the API, so trying to block traffic to the API using IP Restriction. But all the Web Apps as well as the web API has the same VIP and i cant find any other IP address associated with it.

Also to attach the NSG to the subnet(in which ASE is there), we need to add rules which again need specific IP. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have provisioned external ASE. 
"App Service has the ability to allocate a dedicated IP address to an app. This capability is available after you configure an IP-based SSL"

So, you can limit the access to some of your apps inside the ASE by using App-assigned IP-based SSL addresses (Only possible with an External ASE and when IP-based SSL is configured).
When you provision your ASE, you can select how many external IP addresses the system should have including those for IP-based SSL purposes.

please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#ip-addresses and slide nr.14 here https://8gportalvhdsf9v440s15hrt.blob.core.windows.net/ignite2017/session-presentations/BRK3204.PPTX